# Accessing symfony module configuration from other modules

Tags: php, symfony1, module, controller, symfony-1.4

I am developing a somewhat complex, mostly AJAX application using symfony 1.4. It would be very helpful for me to use some custom properties for my modules, which I defined in the *module.yml* configuration files, for example:

```
all:
  first_property: value1
  second_property: value2
```

etc.

This properties would be used mainly for formatting views generated by javascript, using JSON values returned from my modules. For example - in my main module (used to render the base view) controller I wanted to use something like that:

```php
// In frontend/modules/main
$property sfConfig::get('mod_somemodule_someproperty');
```

It won't work because by default properties of a module are not accessible outside of the module by the *sfConfig::get()* method.

My question is:

Is it possible to somehow access these properties?

If not - I would be really grateful if somebody suggested a different way in which I could specify some recurring attributes for my modules and the access them from an outside controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're familiar with the `app.yml` config? Which is used to store configuration settings through the whole application, not just the selected module. This is the place to store more generic settings...

But, that said. You could just open the `module.yml` of your choice with the `sfYaml` class. Something like this (pseudo code)

```
$moduleName = 'module';
$path = sfConfig::get('sf_app_dir').'/modules/'.$moduleName.'/config/module.yml';
$moduleConfig = sfYaml::load($path);
$property = $moduleConfig['all']['first_property'];
```

Optionally, you could merge the items `all` key with the selected environment.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the module configuration outside the module, why not make the configuration  be app level configuration?
And if you want to share the app level configuration between apps, the configuration should be project level.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I could specify the settings application-wide, I only thought it would by more appropriate (or elegant) to set them per module - because they are basically module-level. For example - a property named _visible_fields_, defining which model fields should be visible in the list view.

Comment: Point being it is not more appropriate at module level when you need them across modules.

Comment: So I went with app-level settings. Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've wanted to share any code outside a module, I've just put it in a plugin, from which any module can get at it. I don't know that this works for properties, but I suspect so.